# FFmpeg mp4 compression

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I'm developing photo and video social network ( partially like instagram ). And i'm using **ffmpeg** for mp4 to mp4 file size compression. I achieved 3 time scale factor for file size ( from 13 mb to 2,5 mb ) but very stupidly - 3 times converting output files by the following command-line string :

```
./ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec h264 -acodec mp2 output.mp4
```

I'm a newbee in video-audio codec theory, so i completely lost audio while such compression. So my question is - where is audio? Which option should i use? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use this with no audio loss and upto 2.5 times size compresssion
"-y", "-i", videoPath, "-s", "" + width + "x" + height, "-r", "20", "-c:v", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-c:a", "copy", "-me_method", "zero", "-tune", "fastdecode", "-tune", "zerolatency", "-strict", "-2", "-b:v", "1000k", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", tempFileName

Comment: @Nikita Pronchik check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39444431/3117966) out

Comment: @GyanendraMani - i'm a newbee, so the options are very unfamiliar( all i can say - i wanna preserve the original video pixel size ( or, at least aspect ratio ) and totally reduce file size

Comment: @GyanendraMani - ok, it works, but -pix_fmt yuv720p option raises an error : "Unknown pixel format requested: yuv720p."

Comment: yuv720p do not exist,what other issue are you having?

Comment: @GyanendraMani - video quality is too low, how can i adjust it?

Comment: You need to specify the -vb option to increase the video bitrate for eg : -vb 20M

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123952/discussion-between-gyanendra-mani-and-nikita-pronchik).

Comment: yuv420p is not the resolution. It is the chroma sub-sampling format. Don't change it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MP2 is MPEG-1 Layer 2 audio codec, not expected by many players in a MP4 container. Use AAC or MP3 instead.

The command below will use the default codecs (H264 and AAC):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.mp4
```

For web use, you should include the following two, to be safe:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```